# Files are gone from drive after clamscan

Tags: clamav

I had this oopsie moment. A friend gave me a hard drive with some files and I wanted to scan these before copying them over to my computer. I opened the terminal and switched to the respective folder and ran the following command

```
clamscan --max-filesize=4600M --max-scansize=4600M ./
```

Obviously clamscan informed me that it will only check 4G files, as that is the max and went on to do its thing. As did I. Later I came back and (in my own not paying attention way) turned off the computer (w/o checking the status or result of clamscan). I suspect it was still running when I shut down, but I can't tell for sure. The drive was / is mounted using a SATA to USB dock and is using NTFS as filesystem.

Fast forward to now, the entire folder I was scanning is now gone (it had around 70 files), while other folders on the same drive are still present.

Is this known to happen? Might the folder still be somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `clamscan` will only *read* files and requires prompting before it performs any action (this can be changed by configuration option which you've not told us if you did), but given you didn't cleanly unmount the drive (or at least didn't mention it), I'd just check it's clean (like I would any partition that was forced down via power being flicked off) before I attempted to read/use it. Did you clean umount/shutdown? Did you `fsck`?

Comment: Hello, I did not mention this in my post, but I did not flick the power, but rebooted and booted into a Win10 Partition, that I use from time to time. The disk in question is formatted using a NTFS filesystem. I will check the filesystem tomorrow.

Comment: reboot via command? SysRq key combination? or how?  Being very specific can help us to know where you are with your issue (inc. release info, if server, desktop etc we currently don't know). If it was a NTFS partition then I'd not `fsck` within windows, but a OS that deals with that *file system* natively.